# Proper algorithm to charge LiPo batteries

Tags: lithium-ion, charger, lipo

We are going to develop a new LiPo battery UPS circuit for our handheld. I have read couple of articles and almost all of them recommend to charge the battery based on the following curve. I have also read articles that authors say that reaching the 4.2V limit is sufficient for most cases. Someone please guide me on this issue.

Recommended charge curve:

[image]

Comment: Is there a question here? Why not use a LiPo BMS IC?

Comment: The question is: To charge a LiPo battery, should I strictly follow the curve or reaching the 4.2V level is enough?

Comment: It depends if you want to charge it safely or if you want to make it dangerous. Why don't you want to charge it like it must be charged?

Answer (score 0):

> should I strictly follow the curve

You don't "follow the curve". The voltage curve itself is a result of interaction of battery chemistry and constant current supply. Just as the second (current) curve is a result of holding the voltage constant.

Having said that, any custom circuit based on discrete components will most likely perform worse than specially designed IC, not to mention half a dozen protection functions you are getting for free.

Comment: "any custom circuit based on discrete components will most likely perform worse" -- unless you're *really really good*, in which case you wouldn't need to ask here.

Comment: @TimWescott yep, that about covers it

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the full curve above, you will get close to 100% of the rated mAh on discharge.  If you charge to 4.2V and then disconnect, you will get about 80% of the rated mAh.

This may seem like underutilization, but limiting the battery charge to 80% of the maximum will get you around 10X the number of charge cycles (if you don't discharge it below 20% too often).  A typical battery has a capacity drop of about 10% after ~500 charge/discharge cycles from 0-100%, but about 5000 cycles if you limit it to 20-80%.

You described a UPS, so I'm guessing it'll be topping off for most of its life.  In this case, you'll probably want to limit the max charge, because keeping a LiPo 100% charged full time is really just roasting it to death.  That's why a lot of laptop batteries are useless after a year or so.  Some BIOSes have a setting you can use to limit the battery charge to 80% for this reason.

Comment: If you want to limit the charge, it would probably be better to use the pictured charge profile with the limit set to less than 4.2V.